# Get url parameter with Angular router when refreshing the page

Tags: angular

In Angular 7, I have a page "movie" where I get the movie's id with:

```
this.id = Number(this.route.snapshot.params.id);
```

All is working well when I get the page from a button on an other page. The problem is when I refresh the page, the value is -1 and my url is still the same so this code does not get the value from url ?

I apologize in advance if the problem is related somewhere else, I did not find it.

Comment: can u put example url  in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Single page applications won't support reload.

If you want your route params to persist, you have to use
`LocalStorage` or `SessionStorage`

Please make sure you're clearing them at last.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I'll then use LocalStorage, I guess I juste need to remove the value in the ngOnDestroy(), is that what you mean by "clearing them at last" ?

Comment: This will not work in new browser So not also good way. You should solve your url problem rather than use this way @vince

Comment: Not really in the OnDestroy.. OnDestroy is called when you leave the particular route.. in your case you are reloading.. you can do the local storage clean up may be when your user logs out.

Comment: I believe there's no other option to persist the data on reload. Please suggest if you got an alternate.. that would be really helpful

Comment: If you're coming up with something like retrieving the data from dB through backend. I'll agree but it'll definitely be an overkill. It's just a route param (not any JWT).. So I thought it's no harm using this..

Comment: Also @vince... I would suggest you to use Session storage instead of local storage as local storage won't have expiration and session storage gets cleared once you close your browser (or once your session ends)

Answer (score 0):

I tried with session storage and it work pretty well but now, I can't get my movie with :

```
this.movies.findIndex(
  (movie) => movie.id === id
);
```

This method return undefined, I checked my Array which is good. It make no sense for me. But for the first problem I wanted help, it seems to work ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
  // for refresh  
  this.router.routerState.root.params.subscribe(c => {
    this.setSelectedPanel(panels.find(p => p.panelId === panelId)!);
  });

  // for navigation
  this.router.events
    .pipe(
      filter(event => event instanceof NavigationEnd),
      map(event => this.getLeafRoute(this.router.routerState.root)?.snapshot.params)
    )
    .subscribe(params => {
      this.id = +params.id
    });

  private getLeafRoute(route: ActivatedRoute): ActivatedRoute | undefined {
    if (route === null) return undefined; //or throw ?
    while (route.firstChild) route = route.firstChild;
    return route;
  }
```

getLeafRoute is for getting the params in the service. so maybe you don't need it.